# Android: Changing a WebView's font size and font style depending on the phone's current settings

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-webview, font-size

Is there a way to change a WebView's font size and font style depending on what the user selected on his/her android phone's settings? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: after testing, i think webview font size adjusts automatically (depending on the user's settings) on lollipop and above, but this is not the case on kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        settings.setTextZoom(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in the case of kitkat

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
}
```

you may use below if condition if needed

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
```